# How can I make my phone to accept many more fingerprints

Tags: android, fingerprint, tee, biometrics

I am working with an Infinix phone. It is running on Android. I have developed an app that allows users to capture fingerprints and use it a time-attendance device. It only limits me to 5 users. How can I let the app accept more users? I have explored the notion of overwriting the existing TEE so I can have the app run and accept as many fingerprints as possible.

Could you please advise?

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific reason about limit.
Fingerprint template also become larger after storing more fingerprints. And to store fingerprint templates is not like to store password in database.

Every time you put finger on sensor it will not in same style. So it may make it harder to read.**Fingerprint modules normally HSM like smart card, so storing is limited.**

While reading the fingerprints the reader have to also make difficult calculation just for one fingerprints, if there are more than one fingerprint available then it will be slightly delay, however calculations are made in parallel thread still it can delay.

So because of such reason, limit is there.